# php update MySql record

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use PHP to do a simple API to update a certain column in a record in my database. However, I am stuck with *Missing parameters error* whenever I try something like `http://localhost/set_is_open.php?open=0&shop_id=2`

Here is my API:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    require_once 'db.php';

    if(!isset($_GET["open"]) || empty(trim($_GET["open"])) || !isset($_GET["shop_id"]) || empty(trim($_GET["shop_id"])))
        die(json_encode(array("error" => "Missing request paramters.")));

    $isOpen = trim($_GET["open"]);
    $shop_id = trim($_GET["shop_id"]);

    if(! $conn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $sql = 'UPDATE shops
                    SET is_open = isOpen
                    WHERE shop_id = shop_id';

    mysql_select_db('shops');
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

I doubt that there is something wrong I am doing maybe in the syntax, but I couldn't figure it out. I followed this tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-update-query.htm)

Comment: You know that using string from the request are a sure way to sql injections in your system? Please use prepared statements instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your `if` condition.

With [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) , the following things are considered empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

And you are inserting `open=0&shop_id=2` as argument so here, `open` variable is assumed an empty.

you simply use,

```
if(!isset($_GET["open"]) || trim($_GET["open"]) == '' || 
   !isset($_GET["shop_id"]) || trim($_GET["shop_id"] == ''))
    die(json_encode(array("error" => "Missing request paramters.")));
```

Other point is that `mysql` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` is best. Also use prepared statements for security.

Read : 
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your current query string

```
$sql = 'UPDATE shops SET is_open = isOpen WHERE shop_id=shop_id'
```

with

```
$sql = "UPDATE shops SET is_open = '$isOpen' WHERE shop_id='$shop_id'"
```

PHP can then replace the variables in your string by the values that you set before.

**Anyways, using the mysql API is deprecated and in the way you do it, also unsafe. Use PDO or mysqli in combination with prepared statements instead.**

Comment: @Behavesh Gangani Why am I getting( Could not update data: Unknown column '$shop_id' in 'where clause') when adding the dollar sign I am getting no syntax error but the database is not actually updated?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the if-condition: `empty(trim($_GET["open"]))`.

When `open=0`, `empty(0) == true`, so you get the *"Missing parameter"* message. You need to change or remove that condition. `is_numeric` could be a good alternative to do that check.

Try this:

```
if(!isset($_GET["open"]) || !is_numeric($_GET["open"]) ||
!isset($_GET["shop_id"]) || !is_numeric($_GET["shop_id"]))
die(json_encode(array("error" => "Missing request paramters.")));
```